# Location live tracking Project

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, backend

I am making a project at which i want to establish a matrix display on a public street which will show the remaining time a bus needs to arrive.

In the bus i have putted a mobile which is uploading to firebase its location.

On the other hand i have an apache-server running php (i cant change to different server). I want to take from firebase database the coordinates, edit them in php and then provide the calculations through RESTfulApi to public so the matrix display can get them (there is an arduino with gsm-gprs module).

The question is how can i connect the firebase database with my php backend and "notify" somehow the changes so the php can make then some calculations?

Answer (score 0):

There is no official Firebase SDK for PHP, but there is a quite elaborate unofficial SDK here: https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. To learn how to connect to the realtime database with that SDK, have a look at the relevant documentation here: https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/realtime-database.html

Unfortunately the documentation states that:

> The Realtime Database API currently does not support realtime event listeners

So you can't use it to **listen** for updates to the database. If you want to do that, your only option is to implement that yourself on top of Firebase's streaming REST API. For the documentation of that API, see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-streaming

This is not necessarily a simple task, so you may want to consider whether realtime listening is really required.

Comment: Thank you very much but i have searched these. Unfortunately i want somehow to get notified from firebase because every 10-15 seconds a function needs to run inorder to calculate the estimated arrival time of the bus and because the project should provide real-time information thats why i need to have realtime listeners. I read smthng about publish/subscribe method via third party service like PubNub or similars but again i can't figure out how to implement these on firebase and php...

Comment: There is no built-in connection to PubNub. If you want realtime listeners, you will have to code something up against a supported API (such as the streaming REST API) or on a platform for which an SDK exists (such as a Node.js server, e.g. on Cloud Functions).

Comment: If i write a function in php that every X seconds makes a request to the REST api of firebase is that a logical solution?

Comment: Yup. That means you're polling to get the same data. Functionally it can work, although it will frequently lead to a much less efficient solution, since you need to read too frequently, and do all kinds of extra checks in your code.